# C++ Creating files of different extensions

Tags: c++, filesystems, file-handling

I currently have a program made to read files as binary save the content into a variable and write it back to a new file with same extension. I tested the program with different types of files and only some are working. Files like .exe, media files (.mp4, .jpg) does not work while .txt, pdf, doc does work.

To make sure if it's an error in programs read/write, I opened the files thats not working with Notepad++ and copied the whole content into a new file of same extension. Still those files are not working.

So what am I missing? Sorry for bad English. Thanks!

Edit:

```
int archive(string files[], string output, int file_len) {
FILE *read_ptr, *write_ptr;
size_t result;
long file_size;
char *buffer;
char entry_text [8] = "###=###";

for(int c = 0; c < file_len; c++) {
    read_ptr = fopen(files[c].c_str(), "rb");
    if(read_ptr == NULL) {
        cout << files[c] << " : File not found\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << files[c] << " : File found\n";

        write_ptr = fopen(output.c_str(), "ab");

        fseek(read_ptr, 0, SEEK_END);
        file_size = ftell(read_ptr);
        rewind(read_ptr);

        buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*file_size);
        result = fread(buffer, 1, file_size, read_ptr);

        fprintf(write_ptr, "%s %s %d ", entry_text, files[c].c_str(), file_size);
        fwrite(buffer, 1, file_size, write_ptr);

        fclose(write_ptr);
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

Edit2: Fixed

Thanks for all the help guys. The trailing space of the fprintf was causing the error. A space was written into the beginning of all writes.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] so that we can attempt to reproduce the problem. Without code it is anyone's guess what might be happening.

Comment: @pstrjds done, sorry didnt thought it was necessary since content copied straight from text editor failed aswell.

Comment: Just a side note, but you are leaking the buffer memory at every iteration of this loop. If you `malloc` you must `free`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `fprintf` line.  You are writing something into that file, then dumping binary data into it, so you are not making a direct binary copy - basically you are not `reading and writing it back to a new file with same extension.`, but rather you are adding a line of data to the front of the file. In general that is going to mess up your media files and executable files since there is data that is expected at the very beginning of those files. For example take a look at the [JPEG file structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure).

Comment: `entry_text` is undefined

Comment: @pstrjds ya, its kind of a structure I made there. <string to identify entry start> <filename> <file size> <binary content of file> When I'm writing only the binary content is written.

Comment: @DunuraDulshan - From the code posted, you are not just writing the binary content, you are also writing that structure which is causing your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files like executable (.exe), media files (.mp4, .jpg) have their own header which contains necessary data to function, when you reading/writing it like that you basically corrupting these files by displacing necessary data from their original addresses, Notepad++ is probably not copying raw binary data as well.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format

Answer (score 0):

Without code it is difficult to help but general hint would be to check if you open file in proper mode (binary or text). For example `fopen` function has third argument `mode` which tells about mode" http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/